# Display data from a Django model as a Tree view

Tags: python, django, group-by, treeview

I have a Django model as shown below

```
    class operationTemplates(models. Model):
    templateID = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    templateCategory = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    templateName = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True, null=True)
    templatePreopBundle = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    templatePosition = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
```

I want to display the data as a tree view using either CSS and html.
Tree view should order the data by **"templateCategory"** as follows

```
- Category1
|__templateName1
|__templateName2
|__templateName3   
+ Category2
- Category3
|__templateName6
|__templateName7
|__templateName9
|__templateName10
```

my **views.py** has the following;

```
def opnoteAnnotatorHome(request):

    group = {}
    list = operationTemplates.objects.order_by().values_list('templateCategory', flat=True).distinct()
    for cat in list:
        group['cat'] = operationTemplates.objects.filter(templateCategory=cat).values()

    context = {
        'catergoryList': list,
        'group': group
        }

    return render(request, 'opnoteAnnotatorHome.html', context)
```

In my template file I am using CSS and html to display a tree structure as shown above, where templates are ordered under template categories. (CSS code not shown)

```
<td colspan="2">
{% for cat in catergoryList %} 
  <ul id="parent_node">   
      <li><span class="caret">{{ cat }}</span></li>
         {% for x in group.cat %}
           <ul class="nested_child">
             <li>{{x.templateName}}</li>
           </ul>   
         {% endfor %}
  </ul>
 % endfor %}
</td>
```

Unfortunately, the above code only displays the parent nodes and the child nodes remain blank. Can someone please help.

I am using Django2 and Python3.7
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you use template? you use view? how you want to do something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap 4/5 Seems to come with a tree view, so I'd say that might be the easiest way of doing this..

##### View

```py
def do(request):
    packed = {}
    for cat in operationTemplates.objects.all().values_list('templateCategory', flat=True).distinct():
        packed['cat'] = operationTemplates.objects.filter(templateCategory=cat)

    data = {
        'packed': packed
    }
    return render(request, 'thing.html', data)
```

##### Template

- Uses Bootstrap 4

  - see: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/b4/jquery/plugins/treeview/

```html
<script>
    // Treeview Initialization
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.treeview-animated').mdbTreeview();
    });
</script>

<div class="treeview-animated w-20 border mx-4 my-4">
  <h6 class="pt-3 pl-3">Things</h6>
  <hr>
  <ul class="treeview-animated-list mb-3">
    {% for cat, list in packed %}
        <li class="treeview-animated-items">
          <a class="closed">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
            <span>{{cat}}</span>
          </a>
          <ul class="nested">
            {% for i in list %}
                <li>
                  <div class="treeview-animated-element">{{i.name}}
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Dear Nealium, this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Which part?- is it at least rendering the page and the page just isn't looking correct? I've never used this `mdbootstrap` program, so i assume there's a couple steps youve got to do before it'll look pretty

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
def opnoteAnnotatorHome(request):

    group = {}

    list = operationTemplates.objects.order_by().values_list('templateCategory', flat=True).distinct()

    for cat in list:
        opNames = {}
        opNames = operationTemplates.objects.filter(templateCategory=cat).values()
        group[cat] = opNames

    context = {
        'group': group
        }

    return render(request, 'opnoteAnnotatorHome.html', context )
```

CSS file has the following code

```
/* ————————————————————–
  Tree core styles
*/
.tree { margin: 1em; }

.tree input {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  }

.tree input ~ ul { display: none; }

.tree input:checked ~ ul { display: block; }

/* ————————————————————–
  Tree rows
*/
.tree li {
  line-height: 1.2;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0 0 1em 1em;
  }

.tree ul li { padding: 1em 0 0 1em; }

.tree > li:last-child { padding-bottom: 0; }

/* ————————————————————–
  Tree labels
*/
.tree_label {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  /*background: #fff;*/
  }

label.tree_label { cursor: pointer; }

label.tree_label:hover { color: #12d7e6; }

/* ————————————————————–
  Tree expanded icon
*/
label.tree_label:before {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1em 0 -2em;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 1em;
  content: '+';
  text-align: center;
  line-height: .9em;
  }

:checked ~ label.tree_label:before { content: '–'; }

/* ————————————————————–
  Tree branches
*/
.tree li:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: -.5em;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #777;
  content: "";
  }

.tree_label:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -1.5em;
  display: block;
  height: 0.5em;
  width: 1em;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  border-left: 1px solid #777;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 .3em;
  content: '';
  }

label.tree_label:after { border-bottom: 0; }

:checked ~ label.tree_label:after {
  border-radius: 0 .3em 0 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #777;
  border-right: 1px solid #777;
  border-bottom: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0.5em;
  height: auto;
  }

.tree li:last-child:before {
  height: 1em;
  bottom: auto;
  }

.tree > li:last-child:before { display: none; }

.tree_custom {
  display: block;
  background: #eee;
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}
```

my template file has the following code to display the tree view

```
<!-- tree view -->
 <ul class="tree">
  <li>
   <input type="checkbox" id="c0" />
   <label class="tree_label" for="c0">Vascular Surgery</label>
      <ul>
        {% for k, v in group. Items %}
           <li>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" id="c{{forloop.counter}}" />
          <label for="c{{forloop.counter}}" class="tree_label">{{ k }}</label>
            <ul>
              {% for x in v %}
               <li><span class="tree_label"><a href="#">{{ x.templateName }}</a></span></li>
              {% endfor %}
             </ul>
            </li>
           {% endfor %}
         </ul>
       </li>
      </ul>
  <!-- tree view end-->
```